# Parsing DateTime serialized from signalR

Tags: javascript, asp.net, signalr

Using the very nice [signalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) library, I have a broadcast message that sends an object of type `ChangeDetail` to the client browsers. The object sent includes a DateTime property:

```
var change = new ChangeDetail();
change.TimeOfChange = DateTime.Now();
```

When I send this to the clients, SignalR takes care of the serializing of the objects to JSON, but in the client javascript code when I inspect the object, it looks like this:

```
console.log (change.TimeOfChange); --> "/Date(1327332563969)/"
```

How I get that back into a js Date object? I *could* write a regex to get the number, and the Date.parse with that number, but that seems a little cumbersome...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have typically added the following prototype extension to String.

```
String.prototype.toDate = function () {
  "use strict";

  var match = /\/Date\((\d{13})\)\//.exec(this);

  return match === null ? null : new Date(parseInt(match[1], 10));
};
```

Basically you can go `change.TimeOfChange.toDate()` to get back an actual date object

Comment: Cool, adding it to a string extension is a good idea. What does "use strict" do?

Comment: @Matt - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it